How to apply migration changes to a private-isolated Aurora RDS instance
I'm using drizzle-orm to generate migration files for my schema. Recently, I've set up an Aurora PostgreSQL instance on AWS and placed it within a VPC, specifically in a private isolated subnet. Now, I'm seeking guidance on how to apply these SQL files containing schema modifications to my Aurora instance. It's worth noting that I'm relatively new to AWS and I'm managing my infrastructure using AWS CDK. Any insights on the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

I would use an AWS CodeBuild job for that, configured to run in the same VPC as the Aurora instance. CodeBuild's name is a bit misleading, it's really more of a general purpose script runner. You could have it configured to pull your SQL files from your Git repository, and apply those to your database.
